# Excel, VBA, Macro, File - Open or Create, Dialog

Tags: excel, vba, file, output

I am writing a macro in MS excel using VBA. I need to open or create a file to write to.
Potentially the file may have a different extension (i.e. .cal) but internally it just contains text.

I have looked over a lot of examples that create a file by explicitly stating the path for the new file (here's one I found):

```
strFileName = "C:\test.txt"  
Open strFileName For Output As #iFileNumber
```

Other examples open a file which already exists.

I would like to have a popup/dialog which allows the user to "either" open an existing file "or" create a new one. I assume this is possible.

I have played around with the `Application.FileDialog(....)` function using strings/paths and objects without much success so far.

Comment: Show what you have tried and describe what problem that led to, and help will be forthcoming. Also please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, with special emphasis on the "Title" section.

Answer (score 0):

With `Application.FileDialog(...)` your user should be able to create a new text file as they would in Windows Explorer (by right-clicking and selecting New->Text File), they can then select that file to output data to.

The below `SelectFile(...)` function returns the path to a selected file (or an empty string if no file was selected). Using this function as-is it is only possible for the user to select one file, but given the context I would hope this isn't a problem.

```
Public Sub SelectOrCreateFile()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    strFileName = SelectFile

    If strFileName <> "" Then
        Open strFileName For Output As #iFileNum
        '### WRITE YOUR DATA ###
        Close #iFileNum
    End If
End Sub

'Returns File Path of file selected with file selection dialog
Public Function SelectFile(Optional DefaultPath As String = "", _
                           Optional FileType As String = "All Files", _
                           Optional FileExtension As String = "*.*") As String
    Dim F As Object

    Set F = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Set up FileDialog properties
    F.Filters.Clear
    F.Filters.Add FileType, FileExtension
    F.AllowMultiSelect = False
    F.Title = "Select File"
    F.ButtonName = "Select"
    If DefaultPath <> "" Then F.InitialFileName = DefaultPath

    'FileDialog.Show returns False if the user cancels
    If F.show Then
        SelectFile = F.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No File Selected", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
        SelectFile = ""
    End If

    Set F = Nothing
End Function
```

Hope this helps!